# Combobox selection items different from display items

Tags: ms-access

I have a code table that is a used in a combobox. It has an attribute on each code called "isActive" which has a value of "Y" or "N". The code table combobox is used to classify transaction data on the Orders table. For example:

```
  ID  Code       isActive
  --  ---------- --------
   1  Repeat        Y
   2  New           Y
   3  Discount      N
```

I want the list of items to include items that are no longer active (isActive="N") so the text can be displayed if someone looks at an old record that used a code that is no longer active. For example if an Order from last year was classified as "Discount" I want that to show when they look at the order.

However, I want the drop-down list for new orders NOT to display codes that are no longer active, since they only clutter the display. If the drop down only includes the codes where isActive="Y", then the order from last year with the code of "Discount" shows up blank.

How can I get the best of both worlds here?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a particular row visible in the combo list, the combo won't display the text corresponding to the combo's value - no exceptions.

However...

If you sort the `isActive = "N"` entries to the bottom, then sort by `ID` or `Code` as usual, then the inactive entries won't clutter the list (as much), but will still display correctly.  This is most easily done with a query bound to the combo's `recordsource`.

You can also display the isActive column so the users will know what they can and can't select, and prevent selection of `isActive = "N"` entries in the combo's `BeforeUpdate` event.